# Running a seperate file from pressing a button in tkinter. (Python)

Tags: python, tkinter

Code:

```
button_start = tk.Button(self, text= "Start", command=lambda: execute)
button_start.pack(side=tk.TOP)
def execute():
    import horserace as hr
```

Question:
`horserace` is a separate python file that we are trying to run as soon as the button is pressed. However, we are unsure of how to do that. Is there a way we can get the file to run as soon as the button is pressed?

Comment: Put the code you want to run in a function.  Put `import horserace` at the top of your file, and do `horserace.run()` in your function.  An import is only done ONCE, no matter how many times you execute the `import` statement.

Comment: Does `horserace.py` access stuff in main script? If not, you can use `subprocess.Popen()` to execute it independently.

Comment: Also `command=lambda: execute` should be `command=lambda: execute()` instead.

Comment: You hav'nt specified the is you are using, so `os.startfile` or `webbrowser` module might help.

Comment: @acw1668 can you go further into detail regarding subprocess.Popen()? Should I place that into the button command? And no, horserace.py does not access anything in the main script.

Comment: Call `subprocess.Popen([sys.executable, "horserace.py"])` inside `execute()` function.  Refer official document on [`Popen()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen).